# MultipartReaderStream from MultipartSection: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I have encountered a strange problem while upgrading my web app from dotnet core 2.2 to 3.0. I have followed applicable steps from [migration steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

One of my API calls returns HTTP 500. Deeper investigation shows that calling `UploadObjectAsync` on `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient` gives me the error below:

```
Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead
```

I am able to quickly fix this using the following snippet (but I don't want to accept this as a final resolution).

```
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureKestrel(options => { })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
            })
```

The failing API is dealing with multi-part upload into Google Storage. I have narrowed the problem down to [MultipartSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.multipartsection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartSection);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=aspnetcore-3.0) or better yet [MultipartSection.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.multipartsection.body?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebUtilities_MultipartSection_Body) property which returns an internal class `MultipartReaderStream` from assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` (v3.0.0.0).

Something in `MultipartReaderStream` is not compliant. Temporarily swapping out `MultipartSection.Body` for a simple disk file (e.g. `File.Open(@"c:\file")`) works fine. This leads me to believe the problem is not in Google's `StorageClient` but rather the `MultipartReaderStream`. Now before I get suggestions to read the entire stream into `MemoryStream` before uploading to Google Storage, let me just say that I am dealing with huge files which are best not buffered.

Looking at [MultipartReaderStream source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/74360c7d97f9b55b94fecbd6e0598daf0c1b7cd1/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/MultipartReaderStream.cs#L238) it turns out there are multiple occurrences of a synchronous `_innerStream.Read()`. Could this be causing the problem? The same is present even in the [MultipartReaderStream v3.1](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.1/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/MultipartReaderStream.cs).

[EDIT]

After digging even deeper it turns out that it might not be a fault of `MultipartReaderStream` after all. Experimenting further lead me to the conclusion that the issue could be in Google's implementation (or even both). If I throw in my own `Stream` implementation and set a breakpoint at `Read`, I get triggered from Google code. The class [ResumableUpload](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/b7b0755bd0e6022fadd92f62707de1bd8f583662/Src/Support/Google.Apis/Upload/ResumableUpload.cs#L740) seems to also use synchronous reads. Most notably `PrepareNextChunkUnknownSize` method is NOT async and uses synchronous reads.

Comment: This was a "problem" even in 2.2, but 3.0 makes disallowing synchronous I/O the default. Support for true asynchronous handling of multipart content has been bandied about in various issues on github/AspNetCore, and seems to be tracked [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11377) (indirectly, as part of moving to pipes). With synchronous I/O now being disallowed by default these remaining synchronous holdouts will likely get identified and fixed faster, but we're not quite there yet.

Comment: So is there a workaround that doesn't involve reading the entire stream at once? I have just tried reading to MemoryStream before passing it on and it worked but this is far from ideal. Are there any 3rd party libraries that do the work of `MultipartReader`?

Comment: There are two obvious workarounds: either hunker down and rewrite all the code involved that does synchronous I/O to asynchronous (power to you, put in a pull request) or... just set `AllowSynchronousIO` to `true` for now and move on. The prohibition on synchronous I/O is intended to *possibly* increase performance and decrease the *potential* for deadlock. It would be absurd to trade in less-than-optimal code that works but happens to use synchronous I/O in third-party libraries for code that provably performs much worse by pre-buffering everything. Synchronous I/O is not a death sentence.

Comment: The problem was definitely in `Google.Apis` assembly. I created a fix. PR accepted. Waiting for the owners of the project to publish a NuGet update. I welcome you @JeroenMostert to formulate an answer. I'd be happy to give you credit for helping me through this.

Comment: As you put in the actual detective work and even went so far as to construct an actual fix, this is one case where your answer would be much more valuable than mine, as you ultimately solved your own problem. I'll take that over virtual points any day.